# CQRS + ES: Can you process multiple commands in parallel?

Tags: cqrs, event-sourcing

I can see how commands can be executed in a strict one at a time sequence with the CQRS + ES pattern. Having multiple commands executing in parallel would significantly increase the throughput of the system and make use of all the cores I have on the server. But surely this risks concurrency issues?

Take a simple example, two users update the customers name and submit the commands at the same time. In parallel two processes replay previous events to get aggregates into the latest state and then both determine everything is valid. Both then save a new update event. Whichever one saves last would seem to be the winner because any future replay would result in that last update being the customers name.

What if the result of the command is to send an email to the customer. Now we send two emails instead of the expected one. What if the command results in creating a new aggregate that gets attached to the customer using a customer property, we end up with two new aggregates created but one is a zombie because it is never referenced by the customer because the other aggregate has been saved as the reference instead.

It feels like you would need to implement your own transaction locking capability to ensure you never get overwrites and that is a complex solution I would rather avoid!

**UPDATE:**

My example was a little too simple. Imagine we have an **Invoice** and **Item** entries that go into an **Invoice**. After adding/changing/removing an **Item** from the **Invoice** we need to find the new total and set it into the **Invoice.Total** property field.

If in parallel two users both add a new **Item** then the total would be wrong with no explicit locking mechanism. Both recreate the **Invoice** aggregate and the existing list of **Item** child aggregates for that **Invoice**. In parallel both create a new **Item** and then add up the new total and set it to the **Invoice.Total** property.

Both then save events for these actions. But now we have an error because whichever command finished last will have a total that does not include the new item from the instance that finished first. This has nothing to do with pessimistic/optimistic concurrency but with transactional locking.

Comment: see my updated answer

Answer (score 6):

> I can see how commands can be executed in a strict one at a time
>   sequence with the CQRS + ES pattern. Having multiple commands
>   executing in parallel would significantly increase the throughput of
>   the system and make use of all the cores I have on the server. But
>   surely this risks concurrency issues?

From the `CQRS+ES` point of view there is not concurrency issue. Any good `Event store` implementation has a `Aggregate` version constraint that guards against concurrent event addition on the same `Aggregate`, using optimistic locking for example.

UPDATE: `CQRS+ES` loves and welcomes concurrent commands.

> What if the result of the command is to send an email to the customer.
>   Now we send two emails instead of the expected one.

Expected by whom? Again, this is not a `CQRS+ES` problem. This is business design issue. In this particular case you should have designed another bounded context `Aggregate` that deals with sending emails to client, having a business invariant that ensures that multiple emails regarding some topic (i.e. username change) are grouped into a single one, the last one having higher priority.

> What if the command results in creating a new aggregate that gets
>   attached to the customer using a customer property, we end up with two
>   new aggregates created but one is a zombie because it is never
>   referenced by the customer because the other aggregate has been saved
>   as the reference instead.

Again, it depends on your business. From the CQRS+ES point of view there is no problem. Event stores are great at dealing with a lot of data (and this is because an event store is an append only persistence). That zombie aggregate is harmless. It occupies only some events in the event store. In the projections (read models) there is no *pain* as it is not present.

> It feels like you would need to implement your own transaction locking
>   capability to ensure you never get overwrites and that is a complex
>   solution I would rather avoid!

This is a problem that you would have regardless of using CQRS+ES. If this is a business requirement you have to do it anyway.

In the case of two users changing the username at the same time you could do some additional checks and inform the loosing user that other user has modified the username, possibly even showing what username and letting *him* to decide what to do next: retry or cancel.

**AFTER UPDATE:**

> My example was a little too simple. Imagine we have an Invoice and
>   Item entries that go into an Invoice. After adding/changing/removing
>   an Item from the Invoice we need to find the new total and set it into
>   the Invoice.Total property field.
>
> If in parallel two users both add a new Item then the total would be
>   wrong with no explicit locking mechanism. Both recreate the Invoice
>   aggregate and the existing list of Item child aggregates for that
>   Invoice. In parallel both create a new Item and then add up the new
>   total and set it to the Invoice.Total property.
>
> Both then save events for these actions. But now we have an error
>   because whichever command finished last will have a total that does
>   not include the new item from the instance that finished first. This
>   has nothing to do with pessimistic/optimistic concurrency but with
>   transactional locking

I think that you must understand how `Event sourcing` works:
Let's suppose that both users have in front of them the `Invoice` (in fact it is the `Cart` that they see, not the `Invoice`; the `Invoice` is generated after an `Order` is placed, but for the sake of simplicity let's assume that). Let's suppose they see 2 items and every one of them wants to add a new item. both of them initiate a command: `AddAnItemToInvoiceCommand`. This is what happens:

- the command dispatcher/handler receive the commands *at the same time*.
- for each of the commands, it loads the aggregate from the repository, storing the aggregate version, let's suppose that is `10`.
- for each command, the handler calls a method on the aggregate that adds an invoice then it receives the `ItemWasAddedToInvoiceEvent` twice, one for every command handler execution.
- for each command, the handler tries to persist the event to the `Event store`
- for the first event persisting action (it **always** it is a first at a nanosecond level) the event is persisted and the aggregate version is incremented; now it is `11`;
- for the second *identical* event, generated by the second command handler, the event is not persisted because the expected version `10` is not found, as now it is `11`. So, the repository retries the commnand execution (This is very important to understand). That is, the *all* command execution is called again: the aggregate is loaded again from the repository, now at version `11`, then the command is applied on it then the event is persisted to the Event store.

So, two events are added to the event store, so the Invoice has the correct state: now there are 4 items with a correct total price being the sum of all 4.

Comment: Using a traditional database the action of writing and reading from records automatically handles the locking for you, it was the database does. Doing it in CQRS+ES is outside a database and so I would need to do it manually. That was my thinking with it adding complexity.

Comment: Yes, but in Event sourcing you don't overwrite ever events, you just append them and you must create an `aggregate version constraint` manually. My answer put the emphasis on the fact that `CQRS+ES` does not resolve design issues. There are some things that you have to do regardless of using `CQRS` with or without `Event sourcing`

Comment: Thanks, you make some good points and I understand the pattern better now.

Answer (score 3):

This isn't really a [cqrs](/questions/tagged/cqrs) issue at all; it's really specific to event storage, and a particular strategy of event storage.

> Take a simple example, two users update the customers name and submit the commands at the same time. In parallel two processes replay previous events to get aggregates into the latest state and then both determine everything is valid. Both then save a new update event. Whichever one saves last would seem to be the winner because any future replay would result in that last update being the customers name.

There are a few things to notice here -- one is that the same issue exists if these commands are run sequentially; the second undoes the effects of the first. Which is exactly the behavior you would want in some cases; example fixing a spelling error.

Second, notice that, because you are just appending, both edits are *preserved*; the two changes both exist in the stream; it's the view (the fold), not the stream, that decides which of the two edits wins.

Which means, to a degree, you aren't done yet -- you still need to correctly model the strategy for choosing the "winner".

In cases where edits can conflict, then you need to take precautions against allowing a write that didn't acknowledge all of the previously accepted writes.  In that case, you don't want to append to a stream, but rather compare and swap.

**Digression**

> Using a traditional database the action of writing and reading from records automatically handles the locking for you, it was the database does. Doing it in CQRS+ES is outside a database and so I would need to do it manually.

Part of your confusion, I believe, is that you are conflating *appending events* with *updating history*.  The literature is not clear on this point, so it may be valuable to review an alternative approach to maintaining a history.

Imagine, for a moment, that you preserve your state not as a *stream* of events, but as a *document* of events.  In the happy path, you load the document, modify your local copy, replace the previous copy with your revision.

In a concurrent write scenario, we have two writers that load the document, make different edits, and then each try to do the replace.  What happens?  If we don't do anything to mitigate concurrent writes, we probably end up with a last writer wins strategy -- corrupting our history by deleting the edits made by the previous writer.

To ensure that we don't lose writes, we need help from the document store.  Specifically, we want some analog of a conditional put (for instance, [mongodb:findAndMofidy](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/command/findAndModify/#dbcmd.findAndModify)).  The second writer should get some flavor of ConcurrentModification response, which it can then mitigate (fail, retry, merge).

Nothing about this changes when we are doing *event sourcing* as she is spoke.

What does change is the nature of the thing that we "PUT"; because we are accepting the discipline that the representations of the events are immutable, and the collection of events is append only, we've restricted the valid edits of a document to a set that allows us to optimize away transferring the entire document every time.

If you like, you can imagine that we send to the event store a description of the changes we want to make to the document.  So the store loads a copy of the document, applies our changes to it, and then stores the updated version.

But the domain model didn't validate that the changes apply to an *arbitrary* version of the history document, but to a specific version of it.  So the message that we send to describe our changes needs to include a reference to the version of the document that we started from.

You can imagine that the "event store" is a linked list in memory.  "Append" is analogous to updating the document without ensuring that it is unchanged from what you verified.  If we need to make sure that our assumptions are still valid (ie, optimistic concurrency), then we need to compare-and-swap the tail pointer; if a  race has allowed some other writer to update the tail since our read, then the CAS operation should fail, and allows us to recover.

A remote event store needs to offer an analogous interface: see the use of [expectedVersion in GetEventStore](http://docs.geteventstore.com/dotnet-api/3.0.1/writing-to-a-stream/#appending-to-a-stream-in-a-single-write).

You may find it valuable to review Udi Dahan's writings on [collaborative domains](http://udidahan.com/2011/04/22/when-to-avoid-cqrs/).

> It feels like you would need to implement your own transaction locking capability to ensure you never get overwrites and that is a complex solution I would rather avoid!

You should keep in mind that you signed on for some sort of locking when you decided to use parallel writers!  Doing the work to control how to maintain data integrity is part of the trade off you signed onto.

The good news, is that *you* don't need implement a transaction locking strategy; you need to choose a data store that provides a transaction locking strategy.

Compare and swap really isn't all that complex, it's [just complicated](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cynefin_framework).

> Both then save events for these actions. But now we have an error because whichever command finished last will have a total that does not include the new item from the instance that finished first. This has nothing to do with pessimistic/optimistic concurrency but with transactional locking.

Right -- you can't blindly append to a stream where you are expecting an invariant to hold.  You have to make sure you are appending to the location that you have checked.

There's an alternative design that you may see from time to time, that treats the history as a graph, rather than as a stream.  So each write potentially forks the history, and you merge later if necessary.  You can get a sense for how that might work reviewing [Kleppmann's work on CRDT](https://martin.kleppmann.com/2016/08/13/json-crdt.html)s

My reading tells me that event graphs are still firmly in the *complex* quadrant.

Comment: Thanks for the detailed answer. The description of the command updating a specific version help clear up the confusion for me.

Answer (score 1):

If two commands are executed on different instances of the aggregate - the answer is trivial, of course you can. Each aggregate is a transactional boundary of its own.

If two commands are executed on the same instance, you have three options to 
handle concurrency:

1. Optimistic concurrency - each command message holds the expected version of the aggregate (the one that was displayed to the user). If the expected version is different from the actual one, an exception is raised and the user is asked to refresh the view. This is the easiest solution.
2. Optimistic concurrency on steroids - Event Sourcing gives you the ability to raise concurrency error only if at least one of the events, that were appended to the aggregate after the expected version, actually conflicts with the command that was submitted by the user. This is best solution from the user interface perspective.
3. Pessimistic concurrency - Here you do lock the aggregate's instance to allow only one user to execute commands on it. In the vast majority of the cases - do go there. This is the most error prone solution, and usually the need for Pessimistic Concurrency is dictated by the business domain.

Comment: This scenario is actually one of the advantages of using CQRS ES. Especially if you implement option 2 above. I have a blog post which covers it in more detail: [Handling Concurrency Conflicts in a CQRS and Event Sourced System](http://danielwhittaker.me/2014/09/29/handling-concurrency-issues-cqrs-event-sourced-system/)

Comment: I think you have missed the point. Both instances of the same aggregate would think there is no concurrency issue. All three of your ways to handle assume that the second instance knows that the first instance change has occurred. That is not the case.

Comment: To write data you execute a conditional write by comparing the expected version of the aggregate, and the one that the transaction is going to overwrite. That's the point of optimistic concurrency.
Read Daniel's blog for details and examples.
(In pessimistic concurrency, it can't happen. But again, don't do it)

Answer (score 0):

Another solution could be that the entity which runs the events is a single threaded, so if you have multiple flights then you could have one such single thread for each flight.

Flight A - One thread handling events for it, a single event will update then both aggregates so one update would not overlap another update.